# Finding A Dynamic Folder

Tags: c#, file, installation

So I am trying to find a Dynamic folder. We have made a game and the game has a sound driver which we provided for the players which is optional. When they download the new patch the driver also gets downloaded and put into a folder called Driver. It is a optional driver to install if one would like. I have the installation Registry Key of where it should be installed. I am asking how can I find the folder called Driver that is in the Game Folder that is downloaded but not ran because its optional. I am curios of how can I find that folder and than running the exe file inside that folder. The catch is, not everyone is going to have the folder installed in the same place. Some may have it on the C Driver, other maybe on the D drive and so on. So I am here to ask for some help. The Code is all being written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

First off scanning the drives for a folder is very inefficient, so you may want to come up with a better way to limit your scan set. One way would be determine a relative path to search within. Following is my quick and dirty [NOTE: Please handle exceptions in a better way], also if possible concatenate your installation path to each local drive (this is assuming that you may only want to install your game on local drives) to limit the scan set.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed);
        foreach (var drive in myDrives)
        {
            var outp = GetAllSubFolders(drive.Name,@"\Driver");
            foreach (var folder in outp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(folder);
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetAllSubFolders(string folder, string pathSubString)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            return dirInfo.GetDirectories().SelectMany(x => GetAllSubFolders(x.FullName, pathSubString))
                .Concat(dirInfo.GetDirectories().Select(x => x.FullName).Where(x => x.Contains(pathSubString)));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

    }
```